# How to find breweries in France that actually make their own beer?

Tags: france, alcohol

I've just moved to France, and I'm in love with craft beer. However, every time I find a *brasserie* ("brewery"), it's 99% of the time a simple bar that has more imports than the "standard" imports (Tripel Karmeliet, Rince Cochon, things like that). If I wanted any of the Belgian imports (I'm in the north of France), I would just go to a specialty beer store in the area where they're cheaper, or go to Belgium directly.

I want *local* stuff made *by the French* - *bière artisanale* (craft beer) made by the establishment. There are a million and one breweries in the U.S. and they're easy to find by searching "brewery" on Google Maps/other services, but nothing seems to understand *brasserie* that well... or these establishments are just mislabeling themselves... or I'm searching the wrong thing!

**How can I find craft beer breweries in France? What search terms should I use, and how can I filter them by establishments that actual *make* beer?**

Comment: google for "micro brasserie"

Comment: I googled your phrase "find craft beer breweries in France" and it turned up many avenues to explore.

Comment: The establishments are not mislabeling themselves.  The word "brasserie" has had a second sense meaning, essentially, "restaurant," [since the late 19th century](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brasserie).  See also https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/brasserie ("grand café où l’on peut également manger") and https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brasserie ("4. Établissement populaire où l’on vend des boissons, notamment de la bière, au détail, et des mets sans prétention.")

Comment: In French, a *brasserie* is actually first and foremost a certain style of restaurant. It does not even need to offer any special beer at all.

Comment: @WeatherVane HA! Well, I googled, in a sense, by using Google Maps. I was on my way out the door so I didn't want to get on "the full internet" (web browser) as I was walking around town :)

Comment: @phoog Good to know, I kind of had that idea in my head already just having been to many *brasseries* before. Slight confusion of vocabulary I guess, since *brasser* means *to brew*... Logical jump would be the noun form. Oh well!

Comment: @Relaxed "first" not in the historical sense, of course.  Chris Cirefice: *brasserie* does *also* (and originally) mean "brewery." It's rather like cafeterias and coffee shops in the US, which do not serve only coffee, much less roast the beans.

Comment: @phoog Good point. I think in terms of efficacy though, sifting through all the *brasserie* would take ages. I don't have time to go to each one and ask if they make their own beer :P I figure I can instead go to the actual *micro brasserie* and then ask *them* if they know of other places in the area ;)

Comment: @phoog & Chris Yes, not in a historical sense but in the sense that's it's currently the preeminent meaning. On the other hand, a business producing beer is still called “brasserie“ today.

Comment: Personally I like Belgian beer. Michelob, Modelo, Rolling Rock, etc

Comment: @JamieClinton I never said I didn't like Belgian beer lol. In fact it's some of the best beer on the planet! But I can get it everywhere in northern France. The more important thing is that... well, none of the beers you mentioned is Belgian. So I'm wondering what the point of your comment is...

Comment: @ChrisCirefice sorry, was just making an irreverent joke about the Belgian company InBev (which owns _everything_)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To have map services like Google Maps find actual breweries correctly, you have to search *micro brasserie*. That filters out the *brasserie*s, which are primarily restaurants, as @phoog mentioned in his comment.

Searching *micro brasserie* found the exact types of establishments I was looking for - places that make and sell their own beer!

Answer (score 3):

Try https://www.ratebeer.com/places/browse/.  Their reviews will often tell you what is served.

Comment: I did take a look at this site, but in fact I was just using the wrong vocabulary in my search. I don't know how up-to-date this website is though - it only shows 1 brewery in Lille when there are actually 3. And in my home city of Grand Rapids, it's missing Jolly Pumpkin and potentially others. Nice site to find good beers though!